# maximum frequency with Google app engine can by hit under free quota?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, limit, quota

What is the maximum frequency ( in per minute) ,  I can hit Google app engine [ using php ] under free quota from my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the limits in GAE console.

> **Per-minute quotas** protect the application from consuming all of its resources in very short periods of time, and prevent other applications from monopolizing a given resource. If your application consumes a resource too quickly and depletes one of the per-minute quotas, the word "Limited" appears next to the appropriate quota on the **Quota Details** screen in the Admin Console. Requests for resources that have hit their per-minute maximum will be denied.